# I have insert the linearGradient tag svg through jquery but Gradient g become small what i shoud do?

Tags: jquery, svg

```
$("stop").wrapAll('<linearGradient id='+ id +'> 
 </linearGradient>');
```

I have inserted the linearGradient tag svg through jquery but Gradient g become small what I should do?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question, there's not enough information here to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Did you miss something in your selector (like class or ID) or do you actually have an element called `stop` in your DOM?